# Request a post to be reopened

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I've re-formuled the question and re-formated my post about RSA in PERl, please check it and if you think is not well-formed let me know so It can be reopened again.
Thanks. 

[Read privateKey with Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA OR Crypt-RSA in PERL [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8747874/1132536)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for making the changes.

That seems reasonable. Reopened.